# Convert Ruby Time to HTML5 global date & time String

Tags: ruby, datetime, date, html, time

In Ruby, how do I convert the`Fixnum` 1291132740128 (milliseconds since the epoch) to the equivalent [HTML5 global time & date string](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-global-date-and-time-string) (Also see [HTML5 time element explanation](http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html#time-element). E.g., 1979-10-14T12:00:00.001-04:00)?

My first attempt is:

```
> Time.at(1291132740128/1000.0).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%Z")
=> "2010-11-30T10:59:00-EST"
```

But, (1) how do I get the milliseconds? Does Time store the milliseconds?
And, (2) how do I get the timezone to be -0400 or -0500, depending on whether it's daylight savings time?

EDIT: Now that I think about it, perhaps it's better to keep it as 1291132740128 and do the conversion with JavaScript according to the browser location. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

1) `%3N` in `strftime` will give you milliseconds:

```
Time.at(1291132740128/1000.0).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N-%Z")
=> "2010-11-30T16:59:00.128-CET"
```

2) Isn't that automatic?

EDIT: What would happen if the user had his JS turned off in that case? I think it depends on the usage.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder what percentage of hits are made by browsers w/o JavaScript enabled... probably very small.

Comment: Anyway, count there search bots as well. If that is, for example, the time when a blog entry has been written, I would certainly try to keep it readable in HTML, not JS.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't show the miliseconds but you could try this:

```
Time.at(1291132740128/1000.0).xmlschema
 => "2010-11-30T16:59:00+01:00"
```